# como puedo modificar el codigo para que grafique correctamente en spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

adjunto codigo de spyder que al momento de ejecutar seleccionando la opcion 1, el resultado del grafico no es el adecuado, puesto que deberia mostrar la evolucion de precios de un determinado bien.

```
plt.title('Evolución de Precios')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

en la imagen se ve como no grafica absolutamente nada. adjunto el formato de lo que estoy graficando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el código que muestras en ningún momento estas especificando que columnas debe usar como valores *x* e *y*. Debes hacer algo como:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


# DataFrame de ejemplo para hacer el código reproducible
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Date": (datetime(2009, 1, 2), datetime(2009, 1, 5), datetime(2009, 1, 6)),
     "Price": (740.3, 769.4, 816.8)
     })

plt.plot(df["Date"], df["Price"])
plt.title('Evolución de Precios')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

o usando `pandas.DataFame.plot` directamente:

```
plot = df.plot(x="Date", y="Price")
plot.set_title('Evolución de Precios')
plot.set_xlabel('Date')
plot.set_ylabel('Price')
plot.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

obviamente cambiando `df` por el nombre que le estés dando a tu *DataFrame*.